# Error while updating records in Mongo DB from Ionic 2/ Angular 3 using Node JS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, ionic2

I have been trying to perform CRUD operations using MEAN and Ionic 2/3. I am new to this hence, this might appear silly. I am trying to update my records on MongoDB. But I don't see it getting updated on my DB, also how do I get a response that data is successfully updated. I seem to getting status as 200 but the records are not getting updated

Here is my code:

This is my server.js

```
// set up ======================================================================
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                 // mongoose for mongodb
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;                // set the port
var database = require('./config/database');            // load the database config
var morgan = require('morgan');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var cors = require('cors');
var messageId = {};

// configuration ===============================================================
// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(database.remoteUrl)
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Can not connect Error:>>',e);
    process.exit();
});
mongoose.connection.once('open', function(d) { 
    console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
})
//app.use(express.static('./public'));      // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'})); // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/vnd.api+json'})); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // override with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header in the request
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");    
    next();
 });
io.set('origins', '*:*');
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/plain'});
    //  res.write("Sever On");
    // res.end();
}),
io = io.listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('User Connected -- Server Online');   
    socket.on('message', function (msg,msgId) {
        io.emit('message', "Hello");
        console.log("message from client:", msg);
         setInterval(function(){
          io.emit("messageStatus",msgId);
      },500)
   });
});

app.use(require('./app/routes/user.js'));
app.listen(port);
//server.listen(port);
console.log("App listening on port " + port);
```

This is my router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserProfile = require('../models/UserProfile.js');
router.get('/User',function(req,res,next){
  UserProfile.find({FullName:req.query.FullName,CI},function(err,data){
      if(err){
        return next(err)
      }
      res.json(data);
  })
})

router.put('/User/:id',function(req,res){
UserProfile.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:req.params.id},{
  FullName:req.body.FullName,
  City:req.body.city
},function(err,data){
    if (err) return next(err);
    else{
      console.log(data);
      res.json(data);
    }

    }) 

})
module.exports = router;
```

This is my models, userprofile.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type:String      
    },
    FullName:{
        type:String       
    },
    EmailID:{
        type:String       
    },
    Phone:{
        type:Number       
    },
    Address1:{
        type:String       
    },
    Address2:{
        type:String       
    },
    PinCode:{
        type:Number       
    },
    Gender:{
        type:String       
    },
    ProfilePic:{
        type:String       
    },
    IDproof:{
        type:String       
    },
    UserName:{
        type:String       
    },
    Password:{
        type:String      
    },
    Dob:{
        type:String       
    },
    City:{
        type:String       
    },
    State:{
        type:String      
    },
    HighestEducation:{
        type:String       

 }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserProfile',ProfileSchema,'User');
```

I have a provider named, profile.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class ProfileProvider {
data : any;
remoteUrl : string = "http://234.234.1.2.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000";
localUrl : string = "http://192.168.0.101:8000/User" ;
headers : any;
  constructor(public http: Http,) {

  }
   public getProfile(EmailID){
    return new Promise(resolve => { 
      this.http.get(this.localUrl+'?EmailID='+EmailID)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          resolve(data);
        });
    });
  }
  public updateProfile(userId,options){
    console.log(">>>>>>",userId,options)
    this.headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
      this.http.put(this.localUrl+'/'+userId,options,this.headers).subscribe((data:any)=>{
        resolve(data);
      })
    })

  }
}
```

And finally my page, profile details.ts I have removed all other irrelevant code. I get the userId from nativestorage(just not mentioned that code here). Currently I am just using the method UpdateRecords() on click of a button.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams ,Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomValidtorsProvider } from '../../providers/custom-validators/custom-validators';
import { ProfileProvider } from '../../providers/profile/profile';
@Component({
  selector: 'personal-details',
  templateUrl: 'personal-details.html',
})
export class PersonalDetailsPage {
  userId : string;
  headers: any; 
  params : any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public ProfileDetails :ProfileProvider, public navParams: NavParams, private nativeStorage : NativeStorage, private fb : FormBuilder,
  private platform : Platform ) 
  {
    platform.ready().then(()=>
    {
      this.nativeStorage.getItem("fbLogin").then((data)=>{
        this.userId = data.id;

      }).catch((c)=>{console.log(c);this.userImg = "http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/fullsize/transformers-x-vol-3/heroic-autobots-1.png"});
      this.nativeStorage.getItem("profileData").then((data)=>{         
      this.userId = data.id;
      }).catch((c)=>{console.log(c)})
    })


  }    

  ionViewDidLoad() {


  }

  UpdateRecords()
  {
   this.params = {FullName:"FirstName LastName1",City:"City1"}
    this.ProfileDetails.updateProfile(this.userId,this.params).then(d=>{
      console.log("Update Record Status >",d)
    }).catch((e)=>{console.log("error:>",e)})
  }
  onSubmit(value: string) : void{ 
    if(this.authForm.valid){
      // 
    }
  }

}
```

In the console log I get this "Update Record Status> Response **{body:"null",status:200,ok:true,statusText:"ok",headers,..}** which I am guessing that it might be updated, but when I check in the Mongo DB and in my collections it doesnt reflect. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be defining `_id` in your schema unless your intent is to manage the ids yourself (this could get nasty).  Mongoose will automatically create this field and manage it for you if you omit the field definition from your schema.

Also, `findAndUpdateById(...)` won't work unless the document already exists in your collection.

If you want to create the record if it doesn't exist, you can use `UserProfile.findOneAndUpdate(query, objectDataToUpdate, { upsert: true })` as defined [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate).  Where `query` could be `{ _id: ObjectId('...') }`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I guess the problem was the `_Id` that you mentioned, I removed it from the schema and it worked!  I already have the record in the database so `findAndUpdateById` works for me